# Grails: Integration testing with multiple/prefixed params e.g. (params["book"])

Tags: testing, grails, groovy, integration-testing, parameters

I've asked the exact same question on nabble [here](http://grails.1312388.n4.nabble.com/Integration-testing-with-multiple-prefixed-params-e-g-params-book-td2548823.html#a2548823)

I'm trying to send params or different domains in the controller integration test.
But can't get them to bind to the domain class with the prefix of "book"

//Controller action being tested

```
def saveBook = {
def book = new Book()
bindData(book, params["book"], [include: ['publicPrivacy', 'description', 'title'])
}
```

//Integration Test -

```
def bookController = BookContoller()
//Doesn't Bind
bookController.params.publicPrivacy = false
bookController.params.description = "Best book in the world"
bookController.params.title = "The world"

bookController.params.book.publicPrivacy = false
bookController.params.book.description = "Best book in the world"
bookController.params.book.title = "The world"

bookController.params["book"].publicPrivacy = false
bookController.params.[book.description] = "Best book in the world"

bookController.saveBook()
```

how do i set the "params" with the prefix to be sent to the controller so they bind to the domain?

Comment: Is this really an integration test? Perhaps just use MockDomain and MockController with functional or unit tests. http://www.grails.org/Testing+Controllers

Comment: no because i'm using the live database and other service methods within the saveBook action. I only gave a little snippet to get the idea across, so do you have any idea how to set the prefixed params on the bookController?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For params namespacing to work, I've had to use a [`org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.servlet.mvc.GrailsParameterMap`](http://www.grails.org/doc/1.1.1/api/org/codehaus/groovy/grails/web/servlet/mvc/GrailsParameterMap.html) for the params object.  For example:

```
def p = ['book.description': "Best book in the world", ...]
def request = [getParameterMap: { -> p }] as javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest

controller.params = new org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.servlet.mvc.GrailsParameterMap(request)
controller.saveBook()
```

Comment: Just to note that everything in the params list has to be marked ".toString()" e.g. ["book.boolean": true.toString()]